# immutable iterator map of tuples scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, iterator, tuples, immutability

I have a map of tuples in `scala` and I want to get just selected key, value pairs from it.

I tried

```
val m1 = {"a":{"0":"R","1":null,"2":null,"3":12.25.0,"4":null}
         ,"b":{"0":"R","1":null,"2":null,"3":34.75,"4":null}
         ,"c":{"0":"R","1":null,"2":null,"3":56.25,"4":null}
         ,"d":{"0":"R","1":null,"2":null,"3":45.65,"4":null}
         }
```

then tried to iterate. But I can't handle this complex expression.

Since I just need to a and b, result will be

```
a-> 12.25

d-> 45.65
```

how can I iterate it in scala?

Comment: What is the type for `m1`? Right now it's not in Scala syntax so the code representation is somewhat meaningless.

Comment: is that tuples or jsons?

Comment: it is tuples. Actually inputs are in a csv file. Just copied a sample input line from it. Code will read it from file and just turn selected key, values as a output.

Comment: @jwvh it a map of tuples. val m1 = Map("...)

Comment: Then please indicate that in your code. Scala tuples are comma separated values within parentheses: `('c',5)` The key/value pair of a `Map` is usually indicated with an arrow, `'d' -> 12`, but you can also use the tuple notation, `('d', 12)`.

Answer (score 0):

The Scala equivalent of your data looks like this:

```
val m1: List[(String, List[(String, Any)])] =
  List("a" -> List("0" -> "R", "1" -> null, "2" -> null, "3" -> 12.25, "4" -> null),
       "b" -> List("0" -> "R", "1" -> null, "2" -> null, "3" -> 34.75, "4" -> null),
       "c" -> List("0" -> "R", "1" -> null, "2" -> null, "3" -> 56.25, "4" -> null),
       "d" -> List("0" -> "R", "1" -> null, "2" -> null, "3" -> 45.65, "4" -> null))
```

Once you have the data in this format, you can extract the data you want like this:

```
val keys = List("a", "d")
val field = 3

m1.collect{ case (k, v) if keys.contains(k) => (k, v(field)._2) }
```

If the order of the data does not matter then you could use `Map` rather than `List` and the code would be slightly cleaner:

```
val field = "3"

m1.collect{ case (k, v) if keys.contains(k) => (k, v(field)) }
```

This would also allow you to remove the `null` values and avoid using `Any`